# How can I start a task in ASP.NET without user interaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, webmatrix

I'm building a site that requires constant monitoring so that we can check to make sure nobody is trying to 'cheat the system' (it's a game). I just want to have a timer that starts (when i publish the site) and never stops. And it must constantly monitor db records, say, every x minutes.

I think what I need is a Web Service but maybe there is another way to approach this?

Note: There will be no 'client/s' connecting to this 'service' or whatever it will be.

Comment: Classes don't start, processes do.

Comment: I apologize, I had a brain majumbo moment where I used the wrong word. Is this possible with Razor code/webmatrix web apps?

Comment: Assuming you control the server, you probably want a Windows Service that runs on the server.  There are plenty of resources on the Internet that describe how to build one.

Answer (score 3):

why not using a WindowsService ? if that's not an option then you need at least one initial request to the webserver for starting a seperate worker thread.

Also if you are using .net4 and  IIS7.5, then you can use of asp.net auto-start feature and get rid of that initial request to start the application :

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Jeff Atwood (co-creator of StackOverflow) describes an interesting technique for doing that here: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Basically it involves hijacking the ASP.NET cache expiration system to do periodic tasks on a regular schedule.

Comment: +1 for cache expiration. have used (thought of it independently) this technique myself as you can specify a callback from the cache object that is to expire. Set up in global.asax application startup or from AssemblyInfo PreApplicationStartup

Answer (score 2):

Either you have to use Auto-Start feature of ASP.net 4.

There are two way

1.http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute.aspx

   Both of above required to start some monitoring thread.
2. Create WindowService that monitor data. Even if you hosted site on third party hosting service, Create web service that provide you data to monitor.
3. Use schedular http://quartznet.sourceforge.net
   Create job to monitor data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way around could be using **Global.asax's Application_Start** method. Refer to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx) for more details.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //code your initial request to start the task
    //use a thread to start the task in the background
}
```

Then you can put the worker thread to sleep for a period of time and then put it back to work once in a while.

Comment: Ah, awesome. Thank you so much. Is there any reason why I can't access database from this file? Not even if I put using declarationn up the top. Am I doing it wrong? It's just a simple select query.

Comment: @Jason I don't know the exact reason, but I do know that it is not a good idea to access the database from this point. You better do it in a class library and then reference it from your web project, this way you can invoke that functionality from the Global.asax. I have done it in that way, also you can have utility classes in your web app that can contain functionality to access your database. Hope this helps and sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

Since the service will not be servicing requests but will essentially be performing a background task, I think a Windows Service will be a good choice.
You can set it up to start automatically at startup.
(I assume you own the web server).